# Completely Custom Context Menu

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

I am trying to create a completely custom context menu for a touch application with a radial style ("pie slices" for each item). I have been able to create one from with a base of ItemsControl. However, when I try to switch this to a base of ContextMenu, I cannot get rid of the default pop-up with each pie slice in a list of items.

Is there any way to override the default ContextMenu style to get rid of this items list functionality?

Edit: This is a screen shot of my problem. The code is almost the exact same between the two examples, other than what class is inherited from and how it displays (adding as a child to a Canvas vs. showing the popup)

[image: Top: The custom context menu inheriting from ItemsControl. Bottom: The same context menu inheriting from ContextMenu]

Edit 2: I tried overriding the default style as below:

```
<ContextMenu.Style>
  <Style TargetType="ContextMenu">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContextMenu">
          <Canvas IsItemsHost="true" Height="100" Width="100" />
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
</ContextMenu.Style>
```

[image: The context menu when overriding the default style.]

Comment: can you add a screenshot and maybe a bit of sample code, please?

Comment: I answered this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15675382/customizing-context-menu-in-wpf/16094841#16094841

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to change appeareance of a WPF control, just change its controltemplate.

Here is the default one for ContextMenu : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744758.aspx

And do not forget to update the MenuItem controltemplate too : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747082(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: StackPanel as ItemsHost is useless here. Custom "CircleItemsPanel" should be developed to display items. Here is the key point, I think.

Comment: I tried this, just using a Canvas to test it out. I posted an edit to the original post, but there is still some underlying functionality to the ContextMenu that doesnt seem to be overwritten by the style.

Comment: Forgot about the MenuItem template

Comment: The MenuItem template seems to be a part of the solution. I do not have it totally working yet, but I think this may be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I personaly don't know any way to override or change default contextmenu layout.
If ever it appears that there is no proper way, I think you should create it from sratch using Adorner class, otherwise by creating a new transparent tomost window.
Keep us informed of the solution you'll choose.

Regards