# Customizing Context Menu in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, contextmenu

I have a project here where I require customizing the context menu in my WPF application in which a button would be placed at the bottom of all the menuitems.

However, if I were to add the button through the XAML, it would appear as another item in the collection in the context menu and the mouse-over highlight would act on it.

I would like to have the context menu tuned to a grid-like style whereby I could customize the style underneath it.

Any idea how I can achieve this (preferably in the XAML)?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's actually pretty straightforward in the XAML.
Just define it under the element for which you want to have the context menu.

```
        <Border>
            <Border.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <!--Put anything you want in here.-->
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </ContextMenu.Template>
                </ContextMenu>
            </Border.ContextMenu>
        </Border>
```

Comment: Great! +1 was looking for this

Comment: Worked perfectly! :)

Answer (score 7):

For your menu item style with the button in the item you can use the following code:

Note - Adding items to the `Header` will keep it in the same `MenuItem`, but if added to the `MenuItem` only it will be regarded as a new `MenuItem`.

```
<ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu.Items>
       <MenuItem>
          <MenuItem.Header>
             <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="Item 1"/>
                <Button Content="Button 1" Margin="5"/>
             </StackPanel>
          </MenuItem.Header>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem>
          <MenuItem.Header>
             <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="Item 2"/>
                <Button Content="Button 2" Margin="5"/>
              </StackPanel>
           </MenuItem.Header>
          </MenuItem>
     </ContextMenu.Items>
 </ContextMenu>
```

This will be the resulting `ContextMenu`:

[image]

From there you can style the `MenuItem` or `Button` etc.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 4):

You can start with the example style/template (from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744758(v=vs.100).aspx)) for `ContextMenu` and adjust it to your needs.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
  <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
  <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
  <Setter Property="Grid.IsSharedSizeScope" Value="true" />
  <Setter Property="HasDropShadow" Value="True" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
        <Border x:Name="Border"
                Background="{StaticResource MenuPopupBrush}"
                BorderThickness="1">
          <Border.BorderBrush>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource BorderMediumColor}" />
          </Border.BorderBrush>
          <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True"
                      KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" />
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Padding" Value="0,3,0,3" />
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="CornerRadius" Value="4" />
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Also see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747082(v=vs.85).aspx for styling `MenuItem`.